# Zend Framework extend module controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

My site structure is currently like this:

```
/cms/
   /data/ - caches etc
   /modules/
   /public/ - aliases from site public folders
/website1
    /images
    /layouts, views, scripts, css etc
    (no index.php because of the alias)
```

This works fine, my system looks to the alias folder to run the app. However, I've now got to the point where I would like to extend one of the module controllers.

Ideally my structure would be:

```
/cms/
   .. as above
   /CLIENT_ID/
       /modules
           ..extending/overriding scripts
```

However, this is the problem: the controller to be called must be called according to Zend's file name structure (Module_IndexController etc), so to extend the base classes would be:

```
Module_IndexController extends Module_IndexController
```

Which obviously wouldn't work nicely. My thought is that it should be:

```
CLIENTID_Module_IndexController extends Module_IndexController
```

But I'm stuck on ideas on how to implement this? I can add the controller directory using: addControllerDirectory on the front controller but I'm guessing I need to change the called class name somewhere?

I can then check if the folder is a directory and run the overriding class rather than the base one.

Any ideas? I'm open to restructuring the folders, but obviously need to keep media files in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the [conventional directory structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html) that Zend_Dispatcher, Zend_Autoloader and Zend_Controller are programed to work with.

In my opinion you have two possible solutions:

1. **customize** Zend_Autoloader and Zend_Controller and Zend_Dispatcher. You can find possible customizations [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.usage), [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.basic) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html#zend.controller.dispatcher.subclassing).
2. **modify** the directory structure.

In this second case consider theese possible projectual choices:

- create independent standalone zend framework projects for all the sites, and create in those the aliases of the CMS folders
- like the previous but customizing the module locations with:
  http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html#zend.controller.modular.directories
- Use the CMS *as a library*: you put all the cms files in folder outside the `/websiteN` and then in websiteN's application.ini you set `includePaths.library = /path/to/cms/folder"`. There are a lot of possible problems in this possibilty, that must be valuated knowing your project. In this way you can call models, extends websites's classes to extend cms's, but you cannot use your cms as the entry point and manager of the user interactions at variuos levels.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can tell Zend the base controller directory for each module.

```
$controller = Zend_controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller->setControllerDirectory(
     array("module_name" => "directory_path")
);
```

I would think Zend would want the naming convention to be ClientId_Module_Controller. But, if you really get stuck with the naming convention, and are using php 5.3 you could use namespaces.